# IE automation send the HTTP Post directly to the form action using VBA

Tags: vba, http-post

I am having some automation trouble.

I am using HTML Object Library to automate an download. At the end of the automation process, I have to click a submit button of a form and then the download starts. 
When I try to handle the dialog with the winapi32 function like this:

```
hWndDialog = 0

'Wait until the dialog is open
While hWndDialog = 0
    hWndDialog = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Dateidownload")
Wend

'get the handle of the button
hWndDialogSpeichern = FindWindowEx(hWndDialog, 0, "Button", "&Speichern")

Call SetForegroundWindow(hWndDialog)

'send message
lRetval = SendMessage(hWndDialogSpeichern, &H5, ByVal 0&, ByVal 0&)
```

Nothing happens. I read something, that this isn't possible, because the dialog is modal?

So I try to send the POST data directly to the form's action. I think this is the best possibility even.

But I don't know what to send to the server.

Here the form in the html page:

```
<form action="/smarti/bismt/bismt/resexport" method="post">
<input class="active" type="button" onclick="submitform()" name="button_export" value="Export">
```

`submitform()` only check some values and then calls:

```
document.forms[0].submit();
```

However, when I send a POST request to "/smarti/bismt/bismt/resexport" I only get the page. I don't know how to set up the request header. Tried to use firebug, to see what is sending to the form, but saw nothing I recognized.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding a question mark ? and then the names of the text input boxes? Like http://zip4.usps.com/zip4/zcl_3_results.jsp**?zip5=92101**.